# Intuitive Website owner verification

Tags: web, verify, owner

Hello I'm developing a web app where the user needs to verify that they are the "Owner" of the website. I know there is code verification but how would I check if that verification is on their site without over complicating the verification method?

Also, I'm thinking about giving the site owner an hour to verify, how would I automatically detect if the hour is over and be able to delete them from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Google or Yahoo do this is to require the webmaster to create a file with a special cryptic name (the file length can be 0), which is generated by Google/Yahoo. Could be something like "dsaa6fd4sgfdsf324gd.html". So you generate such a unique (name) string for each websit eto be verified, store it in the DB, and then you go and try to GET it from that site. If the GET succeeds you can set "verified=true" in the DB for that site and file name.

To answer the 1hr question we'd have to know what technology you are using. There are many options to run timed background jobs from a web application. Usually you write the job details into the database, and have a background daemon check the DB periodically and execute any pending jobs. You could tell it (that daemon) to execute a job one hour later to see if the file (see above) exists. Well, you have to do it that way in any case, it's no use simultaneously telling the webmaster to create that file and check for it right away :)

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm using PHP and mysql, most likely I'd use CURL for the verification. 
As for the one hour timer, I'm not sure how I'm going to check for verification without polling my database every hour, which would cause alot of overhead.

Comment: Polling EVERY HOUR does NOT cause "a lot of overhead". (Almost?) all such background job processors for webapps do it that way - and they poll every few SECONDS. The load imposed by this is ridiculous(ly low).
To find such systems type "php background jobs" into google. I immediately found a topic right on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811931/how-to-manage-and-queue-background-jobs
Concrete example: https://github.com/pcdinh/djjob

Comment: Thankyou very much I think I'll run a cron job.

Comment: A solution without an extra daemon system could be to add an "at" job directly from your PHP, to be run 1hr later, executing the appropriate script. Depends on the amount of work - for 1 job/month a daemon system may be overkill - but then, most webservers are 99% idle anyway...